# use php, grep and regex to search and replace lines of code in file

Tags: php, regex, grep

I have a php file that can read the contents of other files perfectly and return them as a string.

```
$contents = $file->read(); // return as string.
```

i need to be able to search and replace certain lines

lines that begin with `$this->Session->setFlash` and end with `, true));` must be replaced with

lines that begin with 
`$this->Session->setFlash` and end with `, true), 'default', array('class'=>'flash_failure'));`

I have grep in my machine, if that helps.

finally after the contents is changed, i have a function that will write the contents back

```
$file->write($contents);
```

I know this helps to find the lines, but I have no idea how to replace.

```
^.*Session->setFlash.*, true\)\);$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is thus:

```
$contents = preg_replace('/^(.*Session->setFlash.*, true\))\);$/m',
                                         "$1, 'default', array('class'=>'flash_failure'));", $contents);
```

the multiline modifier is key.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$contents = $file->read(); // return as string.

// change contents.
$contents = preg_replace('/^(\$this->Session->setFlash.*?), true\)\);$/',"$1, true), 'default', array('class'=>'flash_failure'));",$contents);

$file->write($contents);
```

Comment: your code is working but somehow it does not work on the $contents when i do a $contents= file_get_contents($filename); your code works because i tested here at http://codepad.viper-7.com/V3BS6H

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `does not work`? Try printing the value of `$contents` after you get it using `file_get_contents`

Comment: there are multiple lines inside the file. so i suspect i need to set a /m modifier. but i stll cannot get it to work. see this for more details. http://codepad.viper-7.com/1twh2k